# SLF4J-Log4j logger not logging

Tags: java, tomcat, logging, log4j, slf4j

I am trying to use SLF4J-Log4j for the first time. In every Java class, I define a logger like so:

```
private org.slf4j.Logger logger = org.slf4j.LoggerFactory.getLogger(<TheClass>.class);
```

(And of course, I make sure that the `slf4-log4j12-1.6.4.jar` JAR is on the classpath!)

But whenever I go to use the logger, like `logger.debug("Something interesting happened");` or `logger.error("An error occurred");`, I don't see their output in my log files. However, no exceptions occur and the app (its actually a WAR deployed to Tomcat) runs fine.

Here is the `log4j.properties` file included in the project:

```
# Set the root logger to DEBUG.
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG

# MonitorLog - used to log messages in the Monitor.log file.
log4j.appender.MonitorAppender=org.apache.log4j.FileAppender
log4j.appender.MonitorAppender.File=${catalina.base}/logs/MyAppMonitor.log
log4j.appender.MonitorAppender.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.MonitorAppender.layout.ConversionPattern= %-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n

# Use the MonitorAppender to log all messages.
log4j.logger.*=DEBUG,MonitorAppender
org.quartz.impl.StdSchedulerFactory=DEBUG,MonitorAppender
```

This WAR uses Quartz to cron a few jobs, which is why you see that last entry.

When I check Tomcat's logs/ directory, I see the `MyAppMonitor.log` get created, but it has nothing in it (0 bytes). I've scanned all the typical catalina.out, catalina-, and localhost- logs as well, and none of my log statements are seeing the light of day.

I am thinking:

1. I don't have `log4j.properties` configured right, or
2. I don't have slf4j-log4j configured right, or
3. This is a classpath issue and perhaps the WAR can't find `log4j.properties` (although I would imagine I would see errors or warnings for this), or
4. I'm not using (the API itself) SLF4J correctly, or
5. I never actually created something called `MonitorAppender`, so I'm wondering if this is the problem; I was just following an example I saw online

Can anybody spot where I'm going awrye, or help me troubleshoot this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Check that you don't have the logback jars in the classpath, as otherwise slf4j will try to use logback.

Comment: @Augusto - thanks for the suggestion (+1) but no, those JARs are not in the classpath.

Comment: SLF4J does not give preference for one implementation over another. It will warn about multiple bindings. See also http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings

Comment: Thanks for the input @Ceki (+1) - you are probably the most qualified person in the world to ask this - does anything here look misconfigured to you?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Your `log4j.properties` configuration file is has a number of errors in it. Try with something simple like the following.

```
log4j.debug=true
log4j.rootLogger=DEBUG, CON

log4j.appender.CON=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.CON.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.CON.layout.ConversionPattern=%-4r [%t] %-5p %c %x - %m%n
```

As for the configuration file in your question, the root logger does not have an appender attached. Moreover, the line

```
log4j.logger.*=DEBUG,MonitorAppender
```

is not valid as '*' is not supported.

Comment: Thanks @Ceki (+1) - can anybody help spot what those errors might be?